# Toggling a class and setting an active class in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, toggle

I know how to toggle a class in React and I know how to make a class active. However, I can't work out how to put them both together.

I map over my recipes and render each one. I want to expand a recipe once its clicked and then if clicked again return to it's natural state. but if I have a recipe open and I hit expand on another one then it should close the first one and then expand the new one.

this is my entire component:

```
state = {
    term: '',
    selectedRecipeId: 0
  }

  handleInput = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    this.setState({term: value})
  }

  expandRecipe = (recipeId) => {
    this.setState({ selectedRecipeId: recipeId })
  }

  renderExpandedView = (recipe) => {
    if (this.state.selectedRecipeId === recipe.id){
      return 'recipeContainerExpanded'
    }
    else {
      return null
    }
  }

  resetView = () => {
    this.setState({selectedRecipeId: 0})
  }

  render(){
    const { recipes } = this.props;
    const { term } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Recipes</h1>
        <button onClick={this.resetView}>Reset View</button>
        <input onChange={this.handleInput} />
        <div className="recipesContainer">
          {recipes.filter(recipe => recipe.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) || recipe.ingredients.some(ingredient => ingredient.startsWith(term.toLowerCase()))).map((recipe, index) => (
            <div key={index} className={`recipeContainer ${this.renderExpandedView(recipe)}`}>
              <h3>{recipe.name}</h3>
              <button onClick={() => this.expandRecipe(recipe.id)}>Expand</button>
              <h4>Ingredients</h4>
              <p>{recipe.ingredients.map(ingredient => <p>{ingredient}</p>)}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

this code will expand a recipe and then if you click on another one, it will expand that one and close the previous one. I just want to add functionality that on the second click, closes that recipe but I cant work how to do it without applying the javascript to every recipe.

hope that makes sense

Comment: Just to make sure, are you trying to toggle from expand to collapsed from the same button?

Comment: yes same button but the button is mapped over so each recipe will have it's own button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract recipe to **Recipe** component and use **shouldComponentUpdate** lifecycle method to let React know if a component’s output is not affected by the current change props.

```
export default class Recipe extends Component {
expandRecipe = () => {
    const {onExpand, recipe, isExpanded} = this.props;

    onExpand(isExpanded ? null : recipe.id);
};

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    const {isExpanded} = this.props;

    return isExpanded !== nextProps.isExpanded;
}

render() {
    const {recipe, isExpanded} = this.props;

    return (
        <div className={`recipeContainer ${isExpanded ? 'recipeContainerExpanded' : ''}`}>
            <h3>{recipe.name}</h3>
            <button onClick={this.expandRecipe}>Expand</button>
            <h4>Ingredients</h4>
            <p>{recipe.ingredients.map(ingredient => <p>{ingredient}</p>)}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Pls check the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uk24qw)

Comment: this kinda works but why does the filter behave weird? if you search for pasta, it leaves chicken fry (which is correct) but then if you expand, it changes the word chicken fry to pasta?

Comment: ah, the problem is in key attribute, i replaced index on recipe.id

Comment: ok so let me understand this before I accept it.
1) you have pulled out recipe into it's own component
2) but you are letting the react lifecycle method determine if it should be updated by it's id? thanks

Comment: 1) yes 2) no, it should updated only if isExpanded prop is changed

Answer (score 0):

I just did a demo with my assumptions check the link :
[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7xtliu)

is that you need  ? or give me more details to solve this issue

Comment: almost, I added in another recipe to your example but when i click expand, it expands both. how can I do it so it just does the one?

Comment: ah I forgot to save

Comment: just to be 100% clear, when you click expand it should only expand for that one

Answer (score 0):

Create separate component which will be responsible for expandable.

> Expandalbe.js

```
class Expandable extends React.PureComponent {
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  isExpand: true,
  selectedRecipeId: 0,
};
this.togglePar = :: this.expandRecipe;
}
expandRecipe(recipeId) {
this.setState({
  isExpand: !this.state.isPar,
  selectedRecipeId: recipeId,
});
}
render() {
 return (
  <div>
    <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
    <button onClick={() => this.expandRecipe(this.props.id)}>Expand</button>
    {this.state.isExpand && <div>
      <h4>Ingredients</h4>
      <p>{this.props.ingredients.map(ingredient => <p>{ingredient}</p>)}</p>
      </div>
     }
    </div>
   );
  }
}
```

> ActualComponent

```
  render() {
  const { recipes } = this.props;
  const { term } = this.state;
  return (
  <div>
    <h1>Recipes</h1>
    <button onClick={this.resetView}>Reset View</button>
    <input onChange={this.handleInput} />
    <div className="recipesContainer">
      {recipes.filter(recipe => 
      recipe.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) || 
      recipe.ingredients.some(ingredient => 
      ingredient.startsWith(term.toLowerCase()))).map((recipe, index) => (
        <Expandable key={index} props... />
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
 )
}
```